# Convert Html String into HTMLDocument VBA

Tags: vba, dom, excel, html-parsing

I'm writing a macro to grab the current exchange rate from yahoo but I'm having trouble converting a html string into a HTMLDocument to allow me to search for the required element by id. Here is my code so far but it fails on the debug.print line.

```
Public Sub Forex(currency1 As String, currency2 As String)

Dim oXHTTP As Object
Dim doc As HTMLDocument
Dim url As String
Dim html As String
Dim id As String

Set oXHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

url = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=" & currency1 & currency2 & "=X"

oXHTTP.Open "GET", url, False
oXHTTP.send

html = oXHTTP.responseText
Set oXHTTP = Nothing

Set doc = New HTMLDocument
doc.body.innerHTML = html

id = "yfs_l10_" & currency1 & currency2

Debug.Print doc.getElementById("id").innerText

End Sub
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am making use of method from [excel-vba-http-request-download-data-from-yahoo-finance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18163560/excel-vba-http-request-download-data-from-yahoo-finance):

```
Sub Forex(currency1 As String, currency2 As String)

    Dim url As String, html As String, id As String
    Dim oResult As Variant, oLine As Variant, sRate As String


    url = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=" & currency1 & currency2 & "=X"
    id = "<span id=""yfs_l10_" & currency1 & currency2 & "=x"">"
    html = GetHTTPResult(url)

    oResult = Split(html, vbLf)
    For Each oLine In oResult
        If InStr(1, oLine, id, vbTextCompare) Then
            sRate = Split(Split(oLine, "<span id=""yfs_l10_audusd=x"">")(1), "</span>")(0)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Function GetHTTPResult(sURL As String) As String
    Dim XMLHTTP As Variant, sResult As String

    Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    XMLHTTP.Open "GET", sURL, False
    XMLHTTP.send
    sResult = XMLHTTP.responseText
    Set XMLHTTP = Nothing
    GetHTTPResult = sResult
End Function
```

Comment: I'm a little disappointed that it's not possible to turn a html string into a htmldocument but your solution works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: The original question is answered in this other thread. https://stackoverflow.com/q/9995257/1337544

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there, you just have the id wrong:

```
id = "yfs_l10_" & currency1 & currency2 & "=X"

Debug.Print doc.getElementById(id).innerText
```