# converting a certain <div> from multiple html files to an excel file

Tags: html, excel

I have a lot of product descriptions from my old website which I would like to assemble in some way, and convert them into an excel file that I can use for an import for my new website's CMS.

My real question here is: is there any way of getting all the bits of text included in all the `<div id="description">` tags which are on all the product pages (I downloaded these pages as HTML files from the FTP server of my website)?

Comment: maybe also tell us which language you want to use to process your html.

Comment: CSV might be the way...

Answer (score 0):

All the methods you'll need to do this are included in the [HTMLDocument Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

More specifically, look at the `body` property and its methods.

[Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18567287/convert-html-string-into-htmldocument-vba) is very closely related and should definetly be looked at.