# Upload file to Dropbox through VBA

Tags: vba, dropbox, dropbox-api

Did anyone know a way to send a file to a Dropbox Account through VBA?
It can be a documentation, a link to an API, anything.
I've tried on google but can't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the [dropbox core api](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs), which is all Http requests. For uploading, see specifically [using put](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#files_put) and [using POST](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#files-POST). You can do http requests in VBA. For some reason I'm having a bit of trouble finding an official msdn/windows language reference. But here are some helpful examples:

[excel vba http request download data from yahoo finance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18163560/excel-vba-http-request-download-data-from-yahoo-finance)

http://tkang.blogspot.com/2010/09/sending-http-post-request-with-vba.html

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/ac1c6f10-3d41-4f15-9711-fd78b74f17ad/winhttprequest?forum=exceldev

That should get you started. Just note that dropbox only accepts UTF-8 strings, which isn't usually Windows's specialty. So make sure you're sending strings in the right encoding.

Comment: Thanks Sam, I'll try that way.