# Click on a href in VBA

Tags: vba, href

I want to click on the following link

[image]

I have the class name and the line code I was trying ot use is the following:

```
objIE.document.getElementByClassName("msDataText searchLink").Click
```

This may well be a very basic question.. any guidance

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it is a duplicate question.
A good function `GetHTTPResult` is already available from the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18163560/excel-vba-http-request-download-data-from-yahoo-finance). You need to just pass the url for the GET request to fetch the data. For POST request (this function will not work), you need to make a POST request with postdata.

Also there is a sample for XMLHttpRequest at [link](https://codingislove.com/http-requests-excel-vba/)

```
Function GetHTTPResult(sURL As String) As String
    Dim XMLHTTP As Variant, sResult As String

    Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    XMLHTTP.Open "GET", sURL, False
    XMLHTTP.Send
    Debug.Print "Status: " & XMLHTTP.Status & " - " & XMLHTTP.StatusText
    sResult = XMLHTTP.ResponseText
    Debug.Print "Length of response: " & Len(sResult)
    Set XMLHTTP = Nothing
    GetHTTPResult = sResult
End Function
```

Comment: I will try this, but I thought there may have been a way without actually extracting the reference, to select (or activate) the link. In thesame way I can search by tag the search bottom of google my expectation is that I could .click the link once I pointed to it through a getelementbyclass function.. ah I am using excel 2013 to pull data out finace site (if this add info to the request)

Comment: Actually, after a better seach I found this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24638533/how-do-i-use-excel-vba-to-click-a-link-on-a-web-page. The last comment seems to point at hte solution i was proposing but seems not to work..

Comment: Remove the click, make it as `Dim obj As Object` 
`Set obj = objIE.document.getElementByClassName("msDataText searchLink")` Assign it to an object and in watch window see the details of the object. It will give you some hint.

Comment: out of context...  I attach the full code till the point it crashes..  pleae let me know.